# Enabling snap assists in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-snap-assist

I have installed the Windows 10 Preview Enterprise on a pc with a Windows 8.1 Prof. 
After install I'm unable to get the new snap assist to work correctly, or at least as I assumed it would work.

Right now the only snap I see is to snap the app to a maximized view.

Is there something I have to do to enable this functionality?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of how you believe it should work?  Then provide screenshots of what its doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [Hands-on with Microsoft's new Windows 10: UI changes that look great at first blush](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2689230/hands-on-with-microsofts-new-windows-10-ui-changes-that-look-great-at-first-blush.html)

> In Windows 8, **apps can be snapped by clicking the Windows key and the
>   left or right arrow, snapping them to the left or right of the screen**.
>   That fills half the screen. With Windows 10, up to four apps can be
>   snapped per screen, maximizing your productivity.
>
> What’s neat, though, is that once you snap an app, Windows 10 suggests
>   another, similar app that you might want to snap next to it, from a
>   small collection of windows. The feature is intended to save you the
>   hassle of hunting about through menus to actually construct a virtual
>   desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what apps you have running but the snapping hot keys do NOT work for me if I have UltraMon running. Exit UltraMon and snapping keys work fine.